# Is it possible to save radio buttons appended by javascript?

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

I am trying to append some radio button fields in meta box content. However, when I try to save it into my database it does nothing.

```
$("#result").append("<input 
style='display:inline-block !important; 
margin-top:-152px !important;' 
type='radio' 
name='resimsecimi'
value='"+imageURL+"'>
<img width='180px'height='180px' id='"+ say +"'' src='" + imageURL + "' /><br>");
```

And here you can see my code for saving this meta box data

```
function ozelalankutucuk_kaydet ($post_id) {

if (! isset( $_POST['ozelalankutucuk_nonce'])) {
return;
}

 if (! wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['ozelalankutucuk_nonce'], 'ozelalankutucuk_kaydet' ) ) {
return;
}


if (! current_user_can( 'edit_post', $post_id )) {
return;
}
 if (! isset( $_POST['resimsecimi'])) {
return;
}

// Update the meta field in the database.
update_post_meta( $post_id, '_ozelalan_key', $_POST['resimsecimi'] );

 }
```

Comment: Yes, you can save the string of HTML in your DB - what is your request payload? Is anything being sent on your POST request?

Comment: There is no change in database tables. neither meta key nor value is inserted.

Comment: How are you sending the data to the server?  I do not see a form tag, and frankly `#result` seems like an odd id for a form.  Are you sure you are adding the radio input to the correct form, are you sure the form is using `post` method?

Comment: In Chrome, right click anywhere on window then select "Inspect". In the developer window that opens, select "Network" from the top nav menu, then check the box for "Preserve log". Now when you click whatever button submits your form or sends ajax request, for the URL which will show up in list in developer window (under the 'Name' column), click on URL, then under 'Headers', lookm to make sure Request Method is "POST" and that the Request Payload contains what you need it to

Comment: @Popmedic I am working on WordPress and as you may know, WordPress has a special post update function. This is a kind of meta-box function. Is it possible that PHP can not get the value that is appended by javascript?

Comment: @DavidPartyka Thanks for the detailed description I am appreciated.

I have got a record actually that might be related to this situation which is:
ozelalankutucuk_nonce: 411df7ce9a

I have no idea about what does it mean

And also i have this record: 
resimsecimi: https://www.baslaroto.com/image/cache/catalog/data/000%201/000%2010/murat-131-benzin-otomatik-kubbeli-opar%20(2)-270x270.jpg

Comment: Do you mean the post_updated hook?

Comment: Both the `ozelalankutucuk_nonce: 411df7ce9a` and the `resimsecimi: baslaroto.com/image/cache/catalog/data/000%201/000%2010/…` are the values you want to be sending in the request, at least judging from your PHP code they are...